# What external 2d animation formats can I use in android?

Tags: android, animation, pipeline, file-format, importing

For an artist who won't be dealing directly with the code, what formats for 2d animation could they use that would be portable into an android game?

In my particular case there are no collision requirements or anything, just need to be able to place the animation on screen at a specific point.

Comment: Is this 3D or 2D?

Comment: 2d for now but 3d options would be useful to know for future reference.

Comment: What kind of animations ? Are you talking about videos, or maybe something that could be a sequence of png's or images ?

Comment: the latter, for example a radar-like ping somewhere on the screen.

Comment: I think there has been a failure of communication on my part. I am looking for what file formats I could import into an android application, not how to create the animation in the first place. Basically I was caught off guard in a meeting with an artist and the guy heading the design on a project when he asked her about doing some animation and she asked what format it needed to be in. Google searches for animation and android just link me to how to do it internally and not how to import animation from an existing outside file.

Comment: If your animation is on a sprite sheet, can you not just load that sprite sheet into yout app ? the sprite sheet is just a png or jpg or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the page flipping technique. You generate the animation as a sequence of images, where each image is a frame of animation. Then if you display each image (or frame) in succession, you get your animation.

You could/should also add all the images to the [sprite sheet](http://www.google.com/search?q=sprite+sheet), so that you only need to load one image, and then just display each portion of the sprite sheet that contains the current frame.

So if your animation images are all 64*64 pixels, and let's say you have 4 frames in the animation, you would end up with 4 images that each represent a frame of the animation. Those 4 images would be added to a bigger image or 256 * 64 pixels, and when you render each image to display the animation, you would first render only the 64 * 64 first pixels. Then you move over by 64 pixels and render the next 64 * 64 rectangle of pixels.